# where to find sharepoint 2010 visual studio workflow tutorials

Tags: development, workflow

I'm trying to find some step by step tutorials for how to create custom workflows in visual studio 2010. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've googled and not found too many 'good' resources.
Thanks,!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are from the MSDN SharePoint Developer site and may be helpful-

- [Sharepoint 2010 Developer Training Course - Workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sp2010devtrainingcourse_workflow_unit)
- [Video Center | SharePoint 2010 Development (includes Workflow)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hh298298.aspx)
- [Developing a SharePoint 2010 Workflow with Initiation Form in Visual Studio 2010 (HOL07)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17215)

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 good resources for getting started:

[Sequential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265727.aspx)

[State Machine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508985.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful when I was trying a couple things with work flows

http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/step-by-step-tutorial-creating-workflows-for-sharepoint-2010-step-115/

I also followed the 2007 version and it helped clear things up a bit