# Can I create Workflow without SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Can I create a workflow even I do not have SharePoint Designer?

If yes, How?

I have an InfoPath form created in SharePoint 2010. I have a field for people/groups. By putting the email address in the people/groups and then when I save or submit the form an email message will automatically to the person inputted in the people/group.fields.

Thank you in advance and I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6):

**Can I create a workflow even I do not have SharePoint Designer?**

Yes, you can always create a workflow without having SharePoint designer. But without SharePoint designer, you are restricted to use default available templates of Workflows.

Here is how you can create workflow right from the SharePoint site.

[image]

As per your requirement, you will need SharePoint designer to build your workflow.

Or,

You can create a custom solution using Visual Studio, answers to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/32359/30145) will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. At least i have an idea now. Is it the same in.sharepoint 2010?

Comment: Yes, SP2010 also provide the settings to create workflow, unfortunately I am not having the SP2010 environment. So I am not able to share the snap..

Comment: I see now the workflow in sharepoint 2010. But i only see 2 workflow template: disposition approval and three-state. I do not know which workflow template would match with my requirement that when i save or submit the form an email notification will be send to the person who has email indicated in the form. Aplology for so many question. This is my first time to create a workflow. Thank you

Comment: Default workflow will not help you. You need to go with SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio...

Comment: Ahh.. that is sad. I am not granted for sharepoint designer or visual studio. thank you very much for the help Aakash

Comment: @Eskulin It looks like this answer is helped you, and it's considered the correct answer based on your question, so Please don't forget to **Mark** the correct answer in case it helped you!